# Insert using LAST_INSERT_ID

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

How would I go about inserting while incrementing and using LAST_INSERT_ID? I have a table and trigger as such:

```
CREATE TABLE A(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name char(15),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE B(
    id int NOT NULL,
    name char(15),
    FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES A(id)
);

delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER T
AFTER INSERT ON B
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
     IF (NEW.name LIKE 'A') THEN
          INSERT INTO A VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1, 'A');
     END IF;
END//

delimiter ;
```

I know that `INSERT INTO B VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1, 'A');` doesn't work if I have multiple inserts into B because `LAST_INSERT_ID()` when doing multiple-row inserts, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will return the value of the first row inserted (not the last). How would I go about incrementing the ID so that `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the most recent ID from the inserts`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert the id from `B`, then use the id column:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T
AFTER INSERT ON B
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
     IF (NEW.name LIKE 'A') THEN
          INSERT INTO A VALUES(B.ID + 1, 'A');
     END IF;
END//
```

This seems like a curious expression.  Perhaps your real intention is simply to have an auto incremented id on both tables.

Comment: With this, the first insert I do(where name = 'A'), I get an error of duplicate entry for primary key.

Comment: @Justin . . . I suspect you want an auto-incremented column in `A` then.

Comment: yes the id is auto-incremented in A and the id in B references the id in A

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I could insert into A without id since its auto-incremented.